# SOAP endpoint address in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, service

I am trying to format an endpoint in SOAP using .NET 4.7.2

If i run local via Visual Studio I get the right address format: http://localhost:52066/wsdl/IMyService/

But when I publish to a server, I end up with the address: http://MyServer:8080/

I have set the address in Web.config

```
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.MyService" 
           behaviorConfiguration="MyNamespace.behaviorServiceConfig">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              contract="MyNamespace.IMyService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" 
              binding="mexHttpBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

In endpoint address="" have i also tried to add /wsdl/IMyService/

I have also removed the Service.svc file from the address with following code:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment
    aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" 
    minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0">
  
    <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" 
             relativeAddress="./wsdl/MyService/Service.svc"
             service="MyNamespace.MyService" />
     </serviceActivations>

</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

My goal is to get the published endpoint address shown as: http://MyServer:8080/wsdl?/IMyService/

Edit:

I am able to connect the client to the http://localhost:9999/wsdl
but i need the path to be http://localhost:9999/wsdl?/IMyService/

```
<services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="IMyService.MyServiceBehavior"
            name="IMyService.MyService">
            <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMyService.MyService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9999" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
```

Comment: [This](https://riptutorial.com/wcf/example/11150/adding-a-metadata-endpoint-to-your-service) might help.

Comment: I had already tried that, sorry

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-service-publishing) from Microsoft shows how to publish and what you would end up with to get your service url.  If memory services you might need to enable wsdl in config file for svc.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by creating an self hosted WCF-service

I do have the wsdl at http://localhost:52066/wsdl/IMyService/ and the client can find the service, but when i tries to run the client, it tries and fails to connect to http://localhost:52066/soap/IMyService/

When adding the address, i get the error, that i only can have one http connection.

I have also tried to create an .asmx page, which i was not able to make it self-hosted, but there i was able to connect, maybe because i implemented the C# Web-service interface, so it was generated from the MyService-class

Can anyone give me an hint

Comment: This is not answer. You can add this additional information in your question by editing it.